Preparing metal fulminates through reaction of alcohols and metal nitrates
I saw a few videos on YouTube where mercury fulminate was being made from mercury reacted with nitric acid forming a salt and then reacting it with ethanol forming the fulminate. Does cadmium salt too react with ethanol? and what if we add sodium hydroxide too in it? I studied chemistry years ago and its just a doubt because I watched a video on YouTube. I am not gonna attempt any experiment.

Disclaimer: DO NOT attempt to synthesize cadmium fulminate or any other fulminates. They are extremely sensitive and toxic compounds. This answer is only for educational purpose only

Fulminates other than those of mercury and silver cannot be prepared directly by reaction of the metals with nitric acid and subsequently with ethanol. There are several reasons for it.

Fulminates other than mercury and silver are unstable in the reaction mixture and they decomposes. Only SF and MF are able to be achieved through this reaction pathway.
Fulminic acid readily forms complex salts and therefore the fulminates cannot be isolated
There was a catalytic effect of silver and mercury for which SF and MF are able to be achieved through this reaction pathway. Other metals don't have the catalytic effect.

So, the majority of fulminates were prepared by reaction of the relevant amalgam of the respective metal with mercury/silver fulminate in methanol or ethanol and precipitated by diethyl ether.
$$\ce{Hg(CNO)2 + CdHg_x ->[MeOH] Cd(CNO)2 + (x + 1)Hg}$$
The reaction needs to be driven in the protective atmosphere of inert gas and then vacuum drying the end product.
Some metallic fulminates can also be formed through the direct reaction of powdered metal and MF in a water suspension (see also below note) without boiling. An example here is thallium fulminate:
$$\ce{2Tl + Hg(CNO)2 ->[H2O] 2TlCNO + Hg}$$

Some more info.:
The preparation of other fulminates were very hard to achieve primarily due to formation of double salts or complexes. The first attempt to synthesize fulminate using the above method was sodium fulminate by Carstanjen and Ethenburg in 1882 which is 80 years after the discovery of MF. The alkali and the alkaline earth fulminates always had one molecule of alcohol and couldn't be removed without the end product getting decomposed totally.
The reaction was also made in aqueous environment but in that case, the product formed the monohydrate and it turned more and more yellow thus destroying the purity. Hence, aqueous medium is not recommened for this type of reaction because 1. low solubility 2. hydrolytic dissociation leading to fulminic acid getting polymerized.

Reference

Primary Explosives by Robert Matyáš, Jiří Pachman, Springer Science & Business Media, 2013


As the page is publicly available, the education only disclaimer is rather a moot point. Even if the OP would respect it, others may not.

Even then, it is necessary. As the answerer, it becomes my responsibility to tell about the dangers of the compound. YouTube videos are also available to public, and they also provide a disclaimer. @Poutnik

My point was not the disclaimer, but rather answering itself. IMHO, answers with high abuse potential should not be provided. // Btw Robert and Jiří could be experts from Synthesia Semtín, where Semtex is produced, or from nearby Technical university in Pardubice, where is specialized explosive department, as they are Czech guys.

Hmm, agreed. Maybe it is worth discussing with the community about providing answers to posts involving dangerous chemicals. @Poutnik

Or maybe you have already asked: https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5308/approach-to-sensitive-chemistry-topics-poisons-explosives-drugs-etc
